# pgfplots(table) spreadsheet like formulas

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I'm currently experimenting with the pgfplots and pgfplotstable packages. I noticed the possibility to create new columns (copying or transforming another column) when I was wondering if it was possible to use spreadsheet like formulas (meaning the value of each cell of the new column should be the value of the cell to its left (same row) + the value of the cell above (same column), and yes there has to be some initializing).

Does anyone know of such a feature? And if yes how to do this? (regardless if it is only pgfplotstable or even pgfplots)

Comment: You can look at the [`datatool`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/datatool/datatool-user.pdf) package, see the manual from page 76 onwards. Note that this is different from `pgfplotstable`.

Comment: Hm ok I need to feed the output (the table with the additional column) to pgfplots, is that possible that way? (didn't saw this yet)

Comment: The packages can be combined, see some examples at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pgfplots+datatool.

Comment: Is there a better way to do this than just use `\DTLforeach*{values}{\x=x,\y=y}{
   \addplot coordinates {(\x,\y)};
  }`?

Comment: maybe something with the table option of pgfplots?

Comment: You have in total 4 questions. Three of them have an answer. None is accepted. In addition, apparently no or little upvotes from your side. Do you understand how this community works? :)

Comment: Yes I do ;)  It's just that some of my questions do not have any answers at all (yet) and in many other cases the issue isn't resolved completely up to now. Here actually I just wait if @Marijn writes again about the datatool packacke and how to use it in combination with pgfplots

Comment: well I think I try this in another post, actually this doesn't fit into this one right. This post is about calculations in pgfplotstable and not about datatool ;)

Comment: see [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/533465/use-datatool-to-process-input-and-pass-it-further-to-pgfplots-to-plot-the-data](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/533465/use-datatool-to-process-input-and-pass-it-further-to-pgfplots-to-plot-the-data)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with some limitations using `pgfplotstable`'s `\pgfplotstablecreatecol` macro (also with `create on use` to lazily create the column data, but its contents would then be lost after returning from `\pgfplotstabletypeset`). According to the `pgfplotstable` documentation:

> Currently, you can only access three values of one column at a time: the current row, the previous row and the next row. Access to arbitrary indices is not (yet) supported.

In the example below, I implemented the formula described in the question, initializing it with (arbitrary) value 100 in “row -1.” Since the initial table data is:

```
 x   y
 0   1
 5   6
10  11
```

the computed values are:

- 1 + 100 = 101
- 6 + 101 = 107
- 11 + 107 = 118

In order to access previously-computed values in the column being dynamically created, I store them globally (here: only the most recently computed value, using `\xdef\myPreviousValue{...}`) because `pgfplotstable`'s `\prevrow` macro doesn't give access to values from the column being created, as it seems. If access to *any* previously-computed value in the column being created is desired, one could use a `pgfmath` array<sup>1</sup> or an `expl3` `tl` or `seq` variable, for instance.

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
 x   y
 0   1
 5   6
10  11
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\pgfplotstableread[row sep=newline, col sep=space]{data.csv}\myTable

\newcommand*{\myPreviousValue}{100} % initialization (row -1, sort of)

% Dynamically create column z
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
  create col/assign/.code={%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myValue}{int(\thisrow{y} + \myPreviousValue)}%
    \pgfplotstableset{create col/next content/.expand once={\myValue}}%
    \xdef\myPreviousValue{\myValue}%
  }]
{z}\myTable

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  columns/x/.style={column name={$x$}},
  columns/y/.style={column name={$y$}},
  columns/z/.style={column name={$z$}},
  every head row/.style={before row=\toprule, after row=\midrule},
  every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}
  ]{\myTable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: the `int()` in the `pgfmath` expression I used might appear as unnecessary because by default, `\pgfplotstabletypeset` formats values using `\pgfmathprintnumber` and, again by default, `\pgfmathprintnumber` detects if the input has a fractional part equal to zero in order to special-case the printing of integers. For instance, `\pgfmathprintnumber{118.0}` prints 118 by default. However, without the `int()`, the values stored in `\myValue`—and thus also in the created in-memory column and in `\myPreviousValue`—would have a trailing `.0`; using the `int()` function prevents this.

---

**Footnote**

1. Search the [Ti*k*Z & PGF manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) for “array access operators” in the *Mathematical and Object-Oriented Engines* part.

Comment: Oh, that looks pretty nice just three little questions: in the line `\pgfmathsetmacro{\myValue}{int(\thisrow{y} + \myPreviousValue)}%` what does the `int()` do? Is this some kind of "cast" of the result?

Is there another way to insert tables from `pgfplotstables` to `pgfplots` without macros (I suppose not or is there one?)

And the last one, just curious is there a specific reason why people add a % at the end of the line?

Comment: 1) `int()` is used to obtain an integer, otherwise `\pgfmathparse` and `\pgfmathsetmacro` produce floating point results (try `\show\myValue` in my code after the `\pgfmathsetmacro` line.  2) The table data can very easily be turned into a plot, e.g. with `\usepackage{pgfplots}` and `\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
  \addplot3[color=blue, only marks] table[x=x, y=y, z=z] {\myTable};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}` in my sample document.

Comment: 3) The end-of-line percent signs are very important in many contexts to [avoid spurious spaces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines). In some contexts, they are not necessary: e.g., between comma-separated options when using PGF keys, Ti*k*Z options...

Comment: 1) ok so as I already suspected.

2) yea this is what I meant by inserting my macro (but I don't know a way doing this without it)

3) Oh didn't knew that